# The input device is not a TTY-- Docker

Tags: linux, docker, jenkins-pipeline, devops, jenkins-groovy

I am facing the input device is not a TTY error when i try to execute

```
docker run[docker run -it $(docker images | awk \'{print $3}\' | awk \'NR==2\')]
```

command from jenkins file to enter into container, but its throwing error input device is not TTY, then i tried with detacedh mode

```
docker run -itd $(docker images | awk \'{print $3}\' | awk \'NR==2\') 
docker exec -it $(docker ps | head -2 | tail -1 | awk \'{print $1 }\') bash--
```

this is to enter to container but their also I got same error because `-it` is used.
I have read some solution from stack over flow and tried it below steps.

```
sh 'echo "`docker ps | head -2 | tail -1 | awk \'{print $1 }\'`" | docker run alphie cat'
```

this also throws error `Error: No such container: alpine`
can some one help here

This is my jenkins file

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'pulse_ec2' }
    
    stages {
        stage('Clean workspace') {
            steps {
                cleanWs()
            }
            
            
        }
            stage('Clone adas_bt_wifi_docker_setup repo')
           {
           
               steps {
                  script{
           
                       git url: 'repourl', branch: 'master',
                   credentialsId: 'key'
                       sh 'gzip -d  *.tar.gz'
                       sh 'docker load -i *.tar'
                       sh 'docker images'
                       sh 'docker run -itd $(docker images | awk \'{print $3}\' | awk \'NR==2\')'
                         
                     //sh 'docker exec --rm -i $(docker ps | head -2 | tail -1 | awk \'{print $1}\')'
                      // sh 'docker exec -it $(docker ps | head -2 | tail -1 | awk \'{print $1 }\') bash'
                       def container = echo "`docker ps | head -2 | tail -1 | awk \'{print $1 }\'`"
                       sh 'docker exec -it $container'
                    // sh 'echo "`docker ps | head -2 | tail -1 | awk \'{print $1 }\'`" | docker run cat'
                         sh 'ls -lt'
                       }
                }
           }
    }
}
```

Comment: My guess is that you're not properly logged in to your docker registry and it's trying to prompt for a username and password. Try adding the proper commands to login to docker or make sure the appropriate environment variables are set.

Comment: You might use the [standard Jenkins pipeline Docker support](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/) if it works for you, it might be easier to set up and it deals better with some cases like making the workspace directory accessible.  If you can, I'd also avoid `docker load` in favor of using or running a registry.  What is the image you're trying to actually run?  The `docker run $(docker images ...)` construct looks like it's picking whichever comes first in the image listing, which won't be deterministic.

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze thanks for your reply , here we are downloading customized image from client from gitlab repo(adas_bt_wifi_docker_setup.git) it will clone minerva_bt_dev_docker.tar.gz next  we will unzip this gz file to tar format gzip -d  *.tar.gz..am using docker load command to load the tar file [docker load -i minerva_bt_dev_docker.tar] .. problem here is when i execute this locally it works from jenkins file am getting this error

Comment: @jessehouwing..we are running on aws server where docker installed and docker image we are pulling from git lab repo it is customised one

Comment: `here we are downloading customized image from client from gitlab repo(adas_bt_wifi_docker_setup.git)` Great! So use docker pull and download from gitlab docker repository, why all the gziping. Even so, still use jenkins docker support. And still, even if you want to run some odd commands, put them in a script so you can test them locally.